# Rails + Foundation Sites vs. Webpacker + Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, webpacker

I need somebody to hold my hand on this.. I made it work halfway and have a sense about what's going on but there is one major issues:

- on each reload of my app (when logging in/out or refreshing the page), the Javascript loads retardedly, meaning you see only HTML/CSS for about one second. This also holds while using webpack-dev-server
- my guess is that webpacker recompiles when this happens. Don't know the reason, though. Not shure what the best method for debugging would be as in the Rails logs I don't find any clues

From researching I understand that

- Webpacker and Asset Pipeline share tasks: Webpacker for JS and Asset Pipeline for CSS. Asset Pipeline acting on app/assets/ while webpack goes through app/javascript
- Webpacker CSS handling is switched on/off with the stylesheet_pack_tag reference in application.html.erb and extract_css: false/true in webpacker.yml. I switched both off, so CSS is being handled by Asset Pipeline.

UPDATE: after putting a .scss file in app/assets/stylesheets and linking it through the application.scss, everything is blown, JS and CSS. So something is really at stake here..

Here is my current setup:

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
 @import "./actiontext.scss";
 @import 'foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';
 @import 'settings';
 @include foundation-everything();
```

app/assets/stylesheets/_settings.scss

```
//  Foundation for Sites Settings
//  -----------------------------
//
//  Table of Contents:
//
//   1. Global
//   2. Breakpoints
//   3. The Grid

// ... etc. this sheet is functional!
```

app/javascript/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

import { Foundation } from 'foundation-sites'
import $ from 'jquery'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  $(document).foundation()
});
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack');

// this belongs to Foundation
environment.loaders
    .get('sass')
    .use.find(item => item.loader === 'sass-loader').options.includePaths = [
      'node_modules'
    ]

// Preventing Babel from transpiling NodeModules packages
environment.loaders.delete('nodeModules');
module.exports = environment
```

config/webpack/development.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: This stuff is really confusing and hard to find help with.  I'd like to see answers for questions like this.

Comment: well .. reading [stuff like this in the Foundation forums](https://foundation.discourse.group/t/why-doesnt-zurb-foundation-support-rails-6-anymore/2369) is also not very encouraging. Seems like I am not the only one struggling with it..